# ActiveRecord: difference between collection << object and association = (associate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to, rails-activerecord

Let us take an example:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subscriptions
end

u1 =User.new
s1 = Subscription.new
```

According to me, the following two lines should be equivalent:

```
u1.subscriptions << s1, and 
s1.user = u1
```

However, it seems that it is not the case.
After executing the first line, u1.subscriptions_ids returns [1] but after executing the second line, u1.subscriptions_ids returns [].

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It would make that association after you save s1. In case of u1.subscriptions assignment, you are working with the result of the internal assignment (which is also unsaved). If you wanted to see something equivalent, see s1.user_id after assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
u1.subscriptions << s1
[s1]

u1.subscriptions << s2
[s1,s2]
```

..
..and so on
   adds element to array similar to push method

whereas `s1.user = u1` always assign value to user object

```
s1.user = u2
```

it gives u2